# My shared pref listener wont' listen

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have followed the Google dev docs and come up with the following shared preference activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }


    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pref changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(this.getLocalClassName(), MODE_PRIVATE).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "registered pref listener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(this.getLocalClassName(), MODE_PRIVATE).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have a simple toast message in the onSharedPreferenceChanged method so I can see it working, but it doesn't seem to work.

The only difference with the Google docs is that I am using getApplicationContext() instead of getPreferenceScreen() in the onResume(), because getPreferenceScreen() is showing up as deprecated.

I just need to figure out why its not listening - my preference screen is just full of checkboxes, so I would assume, when I click any of them, the onSharedPreferenceChanged() method is called and I would see my toast.

This simple one has got me stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering your listener to a wrong preference.

Loaded preference from XML resource in SettingsFragment uses default shared preferences so you should register the listener like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
  SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  pref.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  super.onPause();
}
```